# Clean way to break from an if statement in Go

Tags: go

I have the following case:

```golang
if condition {
  if nestedCondition {
    // logic
    // I want to somehow break at this point but also be able
    // to check the outer otherCondition
  }
  if otherNestedCondition {
    // logic
  }
}
if otherCondition {
  //logic
}
```

Is there a way to "break" from `nestedCondition` but also be able to check `otherCondition`?

Comment: Erm... how about wrapping the logic in a function and returning early?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but as well but it's not what I want to do at that point.

Comment: "break" applies to loops, and `if` is not a loop.

Comment: It's how to do it though... unless someone can convince the world that labels and `goto`'s are not evil, but in fact _clean_, a function is the way to go.

Comment: @Adrian I am aware of that ofc. I'm just thinking how it might be possible.

Comment: You could wrap your `if` monstrosouty in a `for { }` so that break will work. But nested `if`, as you have, are pretty universally agreed to be bad form, in any language. So I wouldn't try very hard to accomodate it.

Comment: @Flimzy You could, but wouldn't that be the epitome of code-smell? Surely even Satan himself would recoil in horror at the sight. The question was a _"clean way"_... ;-P

Comment: @Giannis I do feel like this is an X-Y problem here... If you require the first, and later conditions to be checked, _and_ have nested conditions, the outcome of which don't affect the necessity of later conditions, your function is just bloated. A function should do 1 thing, and 1 thing only. Yours certainly looks to be doing multiple things that really belong in separate functions.

Comment: @Flimzy I did ask for a clean way. If this part of code needs some refactor to cope with that if hell is another story

Comment: The clean way is to either re-factor/re-order your if statments, so nested ones aren't necessary, or to extract them into a separate function, so that an early return is possible.

Comment: Why not change it to `} else if otherNestedCondition {`?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I agree with everything that you said. Just wanted to know if there is a possible way to do this without all the above shenanigans. Thank for the insights though

Comment: @Gavin In general I believe that you should avoid else if in production code because they tend to be more "difficult" to follow. With that said this above code block is surely not prod-appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`break`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements) statements only break from [`for`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements), [`switch`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements) or [`select`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements). There is no break statement to break from an [`if`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements) or from an arbitrary [block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks). If possible, restructure and rearrange your conditions so you don't end up in a situation where you'd want to break from an `if`.

What you may also do is use a function (either anonymous or named one), and return from it when you would want to "break":

```
if condition {
    func() {
        if nestedCondition {
            // To break:
            return
        }
        if otherNestedCondition {
            // logic
        }
    }()
}
if otherCondition {
    //logic
}
```

Yet another solution would be to use [`goto`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements) and [labeled](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Labeled_statements) statements:

```
    if condition {
        if nestedCondition {
            // To break:
            goto outside
        }
        if otherNestedCondition {
            // logic
        }
    }
outside:
    if otherCondition {
        //logic
    }
```

Although note that using `goto` is extremely rare in Go (and in most languages), and should not be "overused" (or used at all).

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to "break" from nestedCondition but also be able to check otherCondition?

No.

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten the if clauses:

```
if a {
    if b {
       // do stuff
       // this is where we want to "break"
    }
    if c {
       // do other stuff
    }
}
if d {
   // do even more stuff
}
```

Could turn into

```
e := true
if a && b {
   // do stuff
   e = false
}
if a && c && e { // this will get skipped if e is false
   // do other stuff
}
if d {
   // do even more stuff
}
```

In general, having fewer nested if clauses is easier to read. Or you could hide the complexity in a function as suggested in other posts.

Comment: indeed, this is the way to go and avoid functions. But functions is not hiding complexity. The complexity comes from nesting. Logical flattening is more readable but  also more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Might have to disappoint you but there is no break token for if clauses . Either try to separate the logic into a function and return at a certain point or restructure the if clauses :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the correct way to achieve what you are trying to do is restructuring your flow, this might be an appropriate case to use `goto`.

```
if condition {
  if nestedCondition {
    // logic
    goto otherCondition
  }
  if otherNestedCondition {
    // logic
  }
}

otherCondition:{
  //logic
}
```

You can check out [Golang Specification - goto Statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements)